# Persistency of shared preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a game that uses a shared preference to record the users high score and display this on a statistics page.

My question -> Will this shared preference persist even after the user exits the application? How do I ensure that this data is always retained, will shared preferences do this or do I need to use something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will this shared preference persist even after the user exits the application?

yes!

> How do I ensure that this data is always retained, will shared
>   preferences do this or do I need to use something else?

[See documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, shared preferences are stored until the app is uninstalled or the user clears app data.

See [storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for details on different methods of persisting data.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below link for complete infomation of shared preferences, it will solve your problem.

[Android Shared Preferences](http://kpbird.blogspot.in/2011/04/android-indepth-sharedpreference.html)